# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

One, and only one, of the answers to the question, [What was the first film to depict the American military as villains?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/119223/what-was-the-first-film-to-depict-the-american-military-as-villains) has been deleted by a diamond mod. A reason for the deletion *might* be asserted in a comment on the answer:

> I believe the question is asking for the first movie.

What I don't understand is that the single deleted answer is not the only answer on the question that is not the earliest dated candidate answer.

Two aspects I don't get:

- The deleted answer doesn't seem to be any less appropriate than other answers that remain intact, so why delete only this answer?
- Why summarily delete instead of comment and downvote?

I feel like the question has a bit of an issue in that it's not completely clear what the asker will accept as "military as villains". To me, that means that candidate answers that are dated later than other answers are not by that fact alone not good answers. The asker might consider a later-dated possible answer as a better fit for the criteria than an earlier-dated answer. So date of release alone is, by my reading, not sufficient to discount an answer, pending further clarification from the asker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this was a blunder on my part. The answer shouldn't have been deleted. It's a genuine attempt to answer even if may or may not be correct.

It has been fixed.